# graceful fallback to normal file uploader on mobile devices (windows mobile issue)

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, file-upload, windows-phone

I tried to implement a nice html5 drag and drop [file uploader from desktop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). Everything works nice, but it does not work on mobile devices (not a surprise, as they do not have desktops). So I tried to nicely fallback on normal file uploader, when a user clicks on dropable region.

I used the only solution, I am aware of (so if you know something better, please tell me). Basically I have a dropable region and a `<input type="file">` which is hidden. When I click on a region, input is called.

Cool, it works. In Ipod, Ipad, Iphone. Then I found that the problem with android (I can not use `display: none`, I have to use `visibility : hidden`).

As you can see here

```
<div id="dropzone"> Click </div>
<input id="file" type="file"/>
$('#dropzone').on('click', function(){
    $('#file').click();
})
```

and on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/58Fgb/), it works fine in Android, and iOS devices, but it still fails on windows phone (Nokia Lumia 520). Does anyone know how to fix the problem.

P.S. I also see that popular library [dropzone.js](http://dropzonejs.com) also does not work on windows phone, so I am almost desperate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was surprised to find out that you can not upload any file on any device below `Windows Phone 8.1`:

> File upload functions in browsers assume you have full access to the
>   file system. With WP you do not have unfettered access to the file
>   system on the phone.

[Sourse](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/21)